# Event handling between immutable objects

Tags: java, immutability, fluid

I am making a simple notepad application in Java and trying to use a fluid and immutable style, for the sake of trying it out.  I have found it a lot of fun and am seeing lots of the great advantages that get talked about in regards to functional programming (code clarity etc.).

But I have an issue with event handling in general.  I have one class TextArea that provides a Notepad-like document like you'd expect.  Then I have another class ScrollBar .  They are manipulated by a master class CentralController that keeps the scroll bar and text area working together (not the real class name, it's just for this example).

So if the user presses the down arrow, CentralController simply calls TextArea.withDownArrow() and that returns a new copy of the TextArea with the cursor moved down.  The problem is the Scroll Bar now needs to be moved, so the CentralController needs to know whether the TextArea got scrolled by that down arrow.

My first attempt to solve it was to return an object that contained not only the new TextArea, but also a flag saying whether the scroll needs updating.  That worked well but didn't feel right because I was no longer returning the TextArea whereas you really should in 'proper' functional programming (roughly speaking).

So then I tried having a flag inside TextArea that would get set if TextArea.withDownArrow() caused scrolling.  That also works well but seems wrong to have a method result stored 'globally' in the class.  It also has issues where you might call withDownArrow() twice and then the flag gets overwritten with a new result.

I have read a bit about Reactive Programming and it does seem interesting, but I'm not sure of it's suitable for this situation where you have a 'child' class sending a message to a sibling.

Just to add, I am under the impression normal event handling won't work in this situation.  With immutable objects when you change something you create a new object.  So any objects that try to send an event to a listener will be sending to an old pointer.

Am I missing an obvious way to do this because I feel like I am?  Or is it actually ok to use normal Java event handling techniques and I'm worried about nothing?

Edit: I think I have worked out a good enough solution now.  Even though the class that receives events (ScrollBar) is recreated all the time, the members of that class do not get recreated.  Only things that change.

So I will just have an simple event receiver method in ScrollBar, and TextArea can have a list of listeners (basically the 'normal' way of doing events with listeners).

In summary my error was thinking I needed to send an event to a instance, rather than a member of that instance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to differentiate between value objects and logic objects.  Value objects contain nothing but values, no logic(*).  They can be immutable.

But of course a text area cannot be a value object, nor can a scrollbar be a value object, because they must contain logic.  Nor can they be immutable, because they contain state.  So, scratch all that.  It won't work.

(*) Or at least no logic that deals with external entities, or manipulates any of their own state.

Comment: Just to be clear though, I'm returning a brand new TextArea on every modification.  It is all currently working fairly well (and performs well), but I'm not happy about the events in particular.  Also these objects are part of my 'pure' model and the actual screen drawing method is elsewhere and just looks at the model and renders it.